# iCal event invitations not respecting time zone settings, contradictory

Tags: google-calendar, calendar.app

Products involved: iCal 4.0.4, Google Calendar (apps for domains)

Both the sending and receiving and sending Google accounts are set to Central time zone, Google Calendars both set to Central time zone, and I've even tried setting the specific event's time zone to Central.

iCal is configured to retrieve events from Google's CalDAV, Time zone support is turned on and set to Central. 'Show event times in month view' is on.

Everything seems good so far. The event invite is sent. It shows in iCal, in Google Calendar and the notification email is sent. Attached to the email is the ics file, whose first 9 lines look great:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20110624T150000Z
DTEND:20110624T160000Z
DTSTAMP:20110624T191906Z
```

All the date/time fields have both the T and Z, indicating this is a GMT time and it should be translated to 10 AM locally. Day, Week and Month view in iCal show the invited event as starting at 10 AM.

**However, upon double clicking to see the event detail, it shows as 3 PM.**

No matter how I go about accepting the event
 - Automatically retrieving invitations from Mail and clicking 'Accept' in iCal
 - Adding the ics file manually and clicking 'Accept' in iCal
 - Clicking the 'Yes' link in the invitation email
 - Accepting the event in web-based Google Calendar
The result is always the same as in the above screen shot.